# No SaveChanges Method on IConfigurationDbContext with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to create my own UI to CRUD Identity clients into Identity Server 4 using ef-core and dotnet 3.1 but I have an issue where I my ConfigurationDbContext doesn't have a SaveChanges() method.

I can read existing data from the database no without any issues and I have the Add() method but weirdly the SaveChanges() method is just missing...

I have injected the service as follows.

```
 private readonly IConfigurationDbContext ConfigurationDbContext;
 private readonly IPersistedGrantDbContext PersistedGrantDbContext;

public ResourceManagementController(
    IConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext,
    IPersistedGrantDbContext persistedGrantDbContext)
      {
          ConfigurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
          PersistedGrantDbContext = persistedGrantDbContext;
      }
```

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730181/ef-objectcontext-savechanges-is-missing), perhaps it can solve it for you

Answer (score 8):

Turns out I needed to Inject ConfigurationDbContext rather than IConfigurationDbContext.
It seems the SaveChanges Method is Inherited directly from DbContext rather than Via IConfigurationDbContext.